# eclipse 2021-09 / how can i shut off javascript autocomplete option?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, autocomplete, editor

**how can i shut off javascript autocomplete option on eclipse 2021-09 version?**

earlier version had JavaScript section, so i could off that option.

but, i couldn't find that menu on lastest version.

i tried shut off that function java editor, general editor, css editor, clientside-javascript editor .... but it won't works.

many assisting functions make a javascript editor too heavy.

and any any proposal for increase an eclipse performance is welcome.

please help ~ and thank you.

Comment: Performance issues are often caused by an installed plugin. So please tell which plugins do you have installed. Do you use [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper) (of which version?) via the _Generic Text Editor_ to edit `.js` files or what exactly are you talking about?

Comment: thanks for your kind. as you said i use Eclipse Wild Web Developer(i couldn't find a version. maybe lastest one i think). and delete that plug-in makes eclipse editor performed better - it's just plain text editor. i just need simple hightlight and font color. Could I change WWD option? just disable autocomple and folding.         and thank you again.

Comment: In _Help > Install New Software..._ work with the update site [`https://download.eclipse.org/wildwebdeveloper/snapshots`](http://download.eclipse.org/wildwebdeveloper/snapshots) to make sure you have the latest version. In the preferences _Language Servers_ you can disable the JavaScript language server. Even without a language server, you will still have syntax coloring in the _Generic Text Edtior_ via TextMate grammars (see preferences _TextMate_).